# aws ubuntu 20.04 mysqlclient couldn't install

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, pip, mysql-workbench

i tried to install mysqlclient but it doesn't work.

this is a part of the error message :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-255:~$ sudo pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)

Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient

  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-s8p2sg7z/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-s8p2sg7z/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-0r3vfxv6

       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-s8p2sg7z/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (44 lines):
  mysql_config --version
  ['8.0.29']

  mysql_config --libs
  ['-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '-lmysqlclient', '-lpthread', '-ldl', '-lz', '-lssl', '-lcrypto', '-lresolv', '-lm', '-lrt']
  mysql_config --cflags
```

i tired with :
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
and this is the error message :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3.8-dev (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
```

i tried to remove the dependencies but nothing work

Answer (score 0):

Before installing MySQL Client you need to activate the virtual environment while installing mysql-client using pip,

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connecting-to-mysql-using-python

Also, make sure you have the latest version of Python

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/using-a-newer-version-of-python

Comment: i tried with venv and i do have the latest python version and it doesn't work

Comment: Follow this configuration https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443146/19229614 instead of mysql-server, use mysql-client in the command